# How to connect to Entity Framework in dynamic way by code in C#?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, database-connection

I need to connect to Entity Framework, but I don't know in the beginning the connection string - only at runtime.

I want to know how can I connect to Entity Framwork with connection string in ASP.NET MVC.

I found this code sample:

```
public class TestEntities : DbContext
{
    public TestEntities() : base(GetSqlConnection(), true)
    {
    }

    public static DbConnection GetSqlConnection()
    {
        // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder. 
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        var connectionSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Current_ADO_Connection_In_Config");

        // Set the provider name. 
        entityBuilder.Provider = connectionSettings.ProviderName;

        // Set the provider-specific connection string. 
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionSettings.ConnectionString;

        // Set the Metadata location. 
        entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl";

        return new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

but I get an error that `ConnectionStrings` isn't a method.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings is not a method, it's a property. You can access your con string like this: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Current_ADO_Connection_In_Config"].ConnectionString;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I found the next code :Expo_DevEntities9 db = new Expo_DevEntities9();
            db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Server = localhost, 1433; Database=Expo_Dev;User Id = dev; Password=dev1234!A"; but I get error: 
Inner Exception 2:
Win32Exception: ‏‏המחשב המרוחק מנע את חיבור הרשת

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor of DbContext tries to fetch the connectionstring from App.Config. One of the other [constructors of DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.) allows you to pass the ConnectionString. I quite often use that constructor to refer to my unit test database.

The Connection string is used in a DbContext factory, that hides for me which database is used to connect:

```
private const string serverName = @".\SQLEXPRESS";
private const string dBName = @"MyUnitTestDb";
private string connectionString = String.Format(
    @"Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=true", 
    serverName,
    dbName);

public MyDbContext CreateDbContext()
{
     return new MyDbContext(connectionString);
}
```